# modify another user's password entry with sudo power

Tags: server, sudo, passwd

what are the sequence of commands to modify another user's password entry with sudo power in ubuntu?

I like to change the other user's pass in ubuntu with sudo power?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just type `sudo passwd username` to change `username`'s password.

Comment: I get asked for usernames password then, how to set a new one without knowing the old?